# How To Delete Comment From Blog Post Step-By-Step

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph API and I have searched these message boards for hours.  I can't seem to figure out How To Delete A Comment From A Blog Post Step-By-Step.  Right now, the url I'm putting into the browser is:  https://graph.facebook.com/{my_ID}?method=delete&access_token={my_access_token}

(the parts in the parentheses is my actual information) 
This is the reply I get:  "(#200) Users can only delete their own comments"

I got the public_stream access token by clicking 'Get Access Token" and checking the box that says "public_stream".

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Also, once I get past this webpage that allows me access, what is my next step?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to delete a comment created by you itself?

In Facebook, delete permission is given to objects (events, comments etc) created by you and those comments and posts created by others on objects owned by you.(comments/posts on your wall, events created by you etc.).

If you want to delete those comments and posts created by others you will need the access token of the owner of those objects.

**"once I get past this webpage that allows me access, what is my next step?"** this is not clear. Please be specific. Will try to help.